# Place string on specific address in .text section

Tags: linker, arm, gnu

I need to place a const string on a specific address within the .text section on an STM32F4. This is what my memory should look like:

```
0x08000000 - 0x08007FFF     reserved for bootloader
0x08008000 - 0x08012FFF     .text (part1)
0x08013000 - 0x0801303F     String constant (64 bytes reserved)
0x08013040 - (end of flash) .text (part2)
```

LD script is currently defined like this:

```
MEMORY
{
  ROM     (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x08008000, LENGTH = 512K
  RAM     (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
}

_IDENTIFICATION_START = 0x8013000;

SECTIONS
{   
  .text :
  {
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
    *(.text*)

    /* < init, ctors, dtors & rodata truncated for readability> */
  } > ROM

  .identification _IDENTIFICATION_START :
  {
    KEEP(*(.identification)) ;
  }

  /* < truncated for readability> */
}
```

But get an overlap-warning.
I tried this:

```
MEMORY
{
  ROM1     (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x08008000, LENGTH = 0xB000
  ROM2    (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x08013080, LENGTH = 512K
  RAM     (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
}

_IDENTIFICATION_START = 0x8013000;
_FWADDRESS_START = 0x8013020;


SECTIONS
{
  .text :
  {
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
    *(.text*)
  } > ROM1

  .text :
  {
    *(.text*)

    /* < init, ctors, dtors & rodata truncated for readability> */
  } > ROM2

  .identification _IDENTIFICATION_START :
  {
    KEEP(*(.identification)) ;
  }

  /* < truncated for readability> */
}
```

Now it totally ignores region ROM1, placing everything in ROM2, but I also need the start of code at 0x08008000 because thats the address the bootloader jumps to.

Does anyone knows how to part the .text, leaving a gap where I can place the string const?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

You can move forward in a section using a relative address like `. = offset`, so we can have a script like:

```
MEMORY
{
  ROM     (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x08008000, LENGTH = 512K
  RAM     (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
}

/** relative address for ID in section */
_IDENTIFICATION_START = 0x8013000 - ORIGIN(ROM);

SECTIONS
{
  .text : {
    /** any code we want first */
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
    *(.text.0)

    /** our fixed address data */
    /** this will fail if we are already pass this address */
    . = _IDENTIFICATION_START;
    identification.s.o(.identification)

    /** rest of code */
    *(.text)
    /* < init, ctors, dtors & rodata truncated for readability> */
  } > ROM

  /* < truncated for readability> */
}
```

We can define the special string in `identification.s`:

```
    .section .identification
    .global identification_string
identification_string:
    .asciz "this is our ID"
```

And code you want in the first part of `.text`:

```
    .section .text.0
    .global _start
    .extern identification_string
_start:
    ...
```

If we compile and link, we get the following output of `objdump -t`:

```
main:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
                         <...>
000000000801300b g       .text  0000000000000000 other
0000000008013000 g       .text  0000000000000000 identification_string
0000000008008000 g       .text  0000000000000000 _start
000000000000b000 g       .text  0000000000000000 _IDENTIFICATION_START
```

where we see that the code begins at `0x08008000`with `_start`, the string is at `0x08013000`, and the symbol `other` from another section `.text` continues right after the string.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it, is to create a section, then use that in source code, like stack in this example [1]:

`char stack[10000] __attribute__ ((section ("STACK"))) = { 0 };`

[1] https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html

Comment: Creating a section and placing a variable in it is not the problem, we already do this in some other projects.
Problem is to place this section within .text section, telling linker to automatically link .text around this section.
Solved this by placing some .o-files .text section manually before the const string and calling
KEEP(*(.identification)) before calling *(.text) in ROM section.
Not the most elegant way as the first .text may change leaving me checking map file now and then to make sure I do not waste to much ROM.
Would still be glad for a more elegant way to solve this

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I've actually had the same problem in the past, but couldn't find a nice solution.